# Unable to set json key value to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I keep getting '[object HTMLParagraphElement]' instead of the ID value.

It should look like this:  http://a-new-url=287&the-rest-of-the-url

I tried setting the console.log output to a variable but I was never able to get it working.  I've also tried using 'value.id' in the URL string but that does not work.

My code:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://some-url',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $(data.results[0]).each(function(index, value) {

            document.querySelector('#search_ID').innerHTML = value.id;
            console.log(value.id)
            });
         }
    });

document.getElementById("ID_url").innerHTML = 'http://a-new-url=' + search_ID + '&the-rest-of-the-url'

</script>


<!-- Displays the ID from the json file I'm accessing -->
<div id="search_ID"></div>  

<!-- Displays the URL -->
<div id="ID_url"></div>
```

Here are my results:

287  ==> This is the correct ID value I was looking for and also is displayed in the console

```
http://a-new-url=[object HTMLParagraphElement]&the-rest-of-the-url
```

I was hoping that someone could show me a way of either correctly setting the console output to a variable or, preferably, be able to set the result of the json query to a variable that I can set the key value to and then insert that into the URL I am creating.

Than you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://some-url',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.results[0]).each(function(index, value) {

        document.querySelector('#search_ID').innerHTML = value.id;
        document.getElementById("ID_url")
               .innerHTML = 'http://a-new-url=' + value.id + '&the-rest-of-the-url'
        });
     }
});

</script>


<!-- Displays the ID from the json file I'm accessing -->
<div id="search_ID"></div>  

<!-- Displays the URL -->
<div id="ID_url"></div>
```

search_ID does not appear in the snippet, so I do not know what it is but I believe what should appear in the URL is value.id.

Comment: It worked!  I was so close.  Thank you for your help!!